# Is there a way to have functions as values of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I have to do multiple operations by taking inputs from the user about what operations are to be done as strings. So I was thinking of making use of a dictionary where the function name would be the key and the value would be the function itself. I also want to pass arguments to the functions. Is there a way to do that?
This is what I want to do:

```
a = [] # an empty list
inp = input() # which function to apply?
arg = int(input()) # the argument corresponding to the function.

# a dictionary mapping all the functions to the names
func_dict = {"append":a.append(), "pop":a.pop(), "extend": a.extend()}
```

I know this won't work, I also want to give the argument that the user entered. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use switch case to do this??

Comment: I don't think python has a switch case though, I've never seen someone use it and haven't found any documentation regarding that I'afraid.

Comment: didn't knew that!. I wonder why they omitted it!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the `()` from the function:

```py
a = [] # an empty list
inp = input() # which function to apply?
arg = int(input()) # the argument corresponding to the function.

# a dictionary mapping all the functions to the names
func_dict = {"append":a.append, "pop":a.pop, "extend": a.extend}
```

This way you'll get the reference for the function and not its result.

EDIT: Then to call the function, use `func_dict['append'](arg)`. Note this solution may fail if you have functions with different number of arguments, so you may have to check that before calling your functions.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer my friend. :)